# getElementById + createElement + parentNode.insertBefore - не работает

Tags: javascript

Смотрю видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URF2sVQWuxU и там на 8:41 автор дает такой код ( но у меня он не работает) :

```
    <div></div>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Фотогалерея</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Еще один пункт</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ovar = document.getElementById('nav');
        var pvar = document.createElement('div');
        pvar.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Меню:'));
    ovar.parentNode.insertBefore(ovar,pvar);

</script>
```

Спросить больше негде, спасибо за любые замечения!

Comment: Вы параметры перепутали: `ovar.parentNode.insertBefore(pvar,ovar);`  а вообще нормальные браузеры в консоли довольно говорящие сообщения об ошибках дают по которым это понять можно секунд за 10

Comment: У меня Firefox - он лучше/хуже о ошибках говорит чем Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поменять местами `pvar` и `ovar` в вызове `insertBefore`, то все работает:

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html lang = "en" >

<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div></div>
    <ul id = "nav">
        <li><a href = "">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href = "">Фотогалерея</a></li>
        <li><a href = "">Еще один пункт</a></li>
        <li><a href = "">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var ovar = document.getElementById("nav");
            var pvar = document.createElement( "div" );
            pvar.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Меню:"));
            ovar.parentNode.insertBefore( pvar, ovar );
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо!! Не додумался бы наверное сам... правда все заработало!

Еще заметил если в коде ошибка где то есть ( у меня перед этим фрагментом стоял display.setAttribute('http://site.org', 'href'); ) то дальше тоже перестает работать

Comment: @Chosenman Находить ошибки очень сложно, так как они молча "проглатываются".

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте `ovar.parentNode.insertBefore(ovar,pvar);` на `ovar.parentNode.insertBefore(pvar, ovar);`